# Generate two object files from the same source file in scons

Tags: scons

Does scons allow to rename the result of Object('foo.cpp') along the 
lines of

```
  o1 = env1.Object('src/foo.cpp', targetname='bar.o')
  o2 = env2.Object('src/foo.cpp', targetname='ney.o')
```

so that I can create two different object files from the same source 
file but different environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it ;-) This can be achieved quite easily by doing:

```
  o1 = env1.Object(source='src/foo.cpp', target='bar.o')
  o2 = env2.Object(source='src/foo.cpp', target='ney.o')
```